# liferay 7 expando taglib import unresolved requirement

Tags: liferay, taglib, expando

I want to use

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/expando" prefix="liferay-expando" %>
  <liferay-expando:custom-attribute-list
        className="<%= User.class.getName() %>"
        classPK="<%= (user != null) ? user.getUserId() : 0 %>"
        editable="<%= true %>"
        label="<%= true %>"
    />
```

but this taglib require resources which are not exported and when I want to deploy I get unresolved requirement error. How to use 
`<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/expando" prefix="liferay-expando" %>`
 in my custom portlet?